# Quand commence-t-on des phrases avec "moi, je" ?

Tags: pronoms, oral, sujet

Quand on commence des phrases avec "moi je" et pas juste "je", ça souligne que le sujet est à la première personne, ou aussi ça permet de faire des contrastes entre le locuteur et quelqu'un d'autre.

Dans le français oral informel, je pense que beaucoup de phrases commencent avec "moi je" et ne commencent pas seulement avec "je". C'est beaucoup plus commun en français que l'analogue en anglais, par exemple. J'ai deux questions similaires.

- Un livre de français nous avertit de ne pas commencer une conversation avec "moi, je". Ça, c'est une règle de grammaire, ou c'est seulement une règle de l'étiquette ? Il semblerait que cela a pour but de commencer une conversation :

> Moi j'aime ces idées, mais toi, tu en penses quoi ?

- Quelles sont les conditions pragmatiques pour commencer une phrase avec "moi, je", et pourquoi est-ce si commun ? Est-ce qu'on l'utilise dans le français oral seulement quand on veut établir un contraste, ou l'utilise-t-on chaque fois quand qu'on change le sujet de la conversation à soi-même ?

---

When we begin phrases with "moi je" and not just "je," that emphasizes that the subject is the first person, or also perhaps contrasts the speaker with someone else.

In spoken, informal French, I think that lots of phrases start with "moi je" and not just "je." It's much more common in French than the analogue in English ("me, I") for example. I have two similar questions about it.

- A French textbook warns not to start a conversation with "moi, je." Is this a grammatical rule, or just an issue of etiquette? It seems to make sense to start a conversation

> Me, I like these ideas. What do you think about them?

- What are the pragmatic conditions for starting a phrase with "moi je," and why is it so common? Is it really true that we only use it in spoken informal language when we want to establish a contrast, or do we use it each time that we change the subject of conversation to ourselves?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Moi je" n'est pas forcément à éviter à l'oral. Il peut être indispensable et tout à fait correct. Pensez au dialogue suivant :

> Albert dit : "J'adore le chocolat".
>
> Gérard lui répond : "J'adore la vanille".

Dit comme ça, la réponse de Gérard est à limite du malpoli, elle ignore presque totalement l'expression, l'existence des goûts d'Albert. En fait, un témoin extérieur à la scène pourrait appeler ça un "dialogue de sourds".

Au contraire, si Gérard répond :

> "Moi, j'aime la vanille"

...la réponse accuse réception de la première opinion. *Moi* est un sous-entendu de "j'ai entendu votre opinion et je réponds par la mienne" ; autrement dit, le "moi" remplace un "quant à moi, je...", "et bien moi..."

Dans cet exemple, il n'y a pas beaucoup de mots qui pourraient remplacer *moi*.

Le dialogue oral nécessite des sortes d'accusés de réceptions de l'existence de l'expression de l'autre. Le "moi" en début de phrase en est un.

Answer (score 8):

Le livre de grammaire évite la tautologie, surtout à l'écrit ; à moins que ce ne soit pour souligner un caractère, une attitude ou rapporter un dialogue le *moi je ...* est à proscrire.

*Moi je ...* à l'oral est une question de contexte, de nuance maîtrisée dans une discussion, d'apostrophe complice où l'on joue un personnage,  ... quand il n'est pas le signe d'un égocentrisme démesuré et inconscient.

À moins de vouloir faire un effet maîtrisé, il est prudent de le réserver aux familiers, et de l'éviter dans les relations conventionnelles ; cela sera une façon de montrer votre maîtrise du français.

Answer (score 3):

Dans certains cas, je pense que le `moi je` permet de renforcer une pensée ou un avis. Comme expliqué dans dans le commentaire précédent, cela permet aussi de faire une sorte d'accusé réception de ce qu'une autre personne vient de dire, par exemple lors d'un dialogue.

Nous avons actuellement un président de la républiques en France qui pendant sa campagne électorale a utilisé mainte fois la formule:

> Moi président ...

Cela sert à renforcer l'idée que quand il sera président il aura un changement par rapports aux précédents. C'est la même idée que le `moi je`.

> Je pense qu'il faut augmenter les impôts.
>
> Moi je pense qu'il ne faut pas.

On sent bien dans la deuxiéme phrase un profond désacord avec le fait d'augmenter les impôts. Dans le cas d'un dialogue, on sent que le ton de la phrase est plus fort, avec une certaine détermination.

L'emploi du `moi je` est plus du ressort de l'oral. A l'écrit, c'est déjà plus rare, sauf dans l'écriture de dialogues (film, pièce de théâtre, ...).

Comment: lol même pas besoin de lire l'explication de ton premier exemple pour savoir d'où tu le tire :)

Answer (score 2):

In spite of what grammar books says, this expression is very common to give your opinion:
Moi, je ne suis pas d'accord.

- Qu'en penses-tu?
- Moi, je pense que...

so, very very common when we speak

Comment: *… so, very very common when we speak* — mais *très, très* familier,

Answer (score 0):

Plus généralement, un sujet peut être *repris*, exprimé deux fois, pour des raisons **grammaticales** (par ex. l'interrogative avec un sujet autre que *il/ce/on* : « La vérité est-elle toujours bonne à dire ? ») ou par **clarté/expressivité** (LBU14 §237). Dans ce dernier cas, « pour insister sur le sujet, notamment pour marquer une opposition, on le reprend sous la forme d'un pronom personnel disjoint » (LBU14 §237 b 3°) :

> *Le ministère,* LUI, *ne faillira pas à sa tâche* (Edgar FAURE, dans le *Monde*, 31 mai 1969). — *Votre père le sait,* LUI. — MOI, *je le sais.*
>   — *Je le sais,* MOI. — NOUS, *nous ne l'étions pas, peut-être,
>   fatigués ?* (E. ROSTAND, *Aiglon*, II, 9)
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup> ex.
>   §237 b 3° ]

Ce phénomène participe de celui de la [*redondance*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/36783) (...expressive pour fins de mise en évidence ; LBU §373). On se rappellera aussi qu'on évoque dans une célèbre chanson un emploi particulier du pronom disjoint « moi » :

> Hier encore, j'avais vingt ans
>  Je gaspillais le temps
>  En croyant
>   l'arrêter
>  Et pour le retenir 
> Même le devancer
>  Je n'ai fait
>   que courir
>  Et me suis essoufflé
>  Ignorant le passé, conjuguant au
>   futur
>  Je précédais de « moi » toute conversation
>  Et donnais
>   mon avis que je voulais le bon
>  Pour critiquer le monde avec
>   désinvolture.
>
> [ Charles Aznavour, *Hier encore* (1964) (extrait) ]

---

Je pense que c'est dans certains cas une forme de mise en évidence désinvolte de sa liberté de s'exprimer ; et donc non, pas uniquement par contraste ; et non, pas nécessairement de manière systématique mais plutôt à sa guise...