# Sujet+pronom à la place du sujet seul

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, syntaxe, linguistique, comparaison-de-langues

J'entends souvent une forme plus longue, moins élégante du type :

> ma famille, elle a ...

plutôt que

> ma famille a ...

- Savez-vous pourquoi elle est utilisée ?
- Porte-t-elle un nom ?
- S'agit-il d'un phénomène linguistique unique au français ou d'autres langues  connaissent-elles un phénomène similaire ?

Comment: Un point de départ: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dislocation_(syntax)

Comment: Merci beaucoup, j'ai fait tout ce que j'ai pu pour trouver un terme technique sur cette structure, mais en vain ! merci

Answer (score 7):

En partant du commentaire de Stéphane Gimenez, j'ai pu trouver une origine à la dislocation, nom de la construction syntaxique exposée dans la question. Mr Grevisse l'a définie en 1993 :

> un terme est mis en évidence au début ou à la fin de la phrase, et un
>   pronom personnel ou démonstratif occupe la place normale de ce terme

Cependant une étude sur les propositions subordonnées de K. Sandfeld qui remonte à 1965 en traite déjà ([les propositions subordonnées](https://books.google.be/books?redir_esc=y&hl=fr&id=nX_bnAAACAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=dislocation)).

Pour répondre à tes questions,

1) la dislocation est utilisée pour insister sur la partie détachée de la phrase, dans ton exemple, l'insistance est mise sur "la famille". De part sa séparation et de la pause marquée avec la virgule, on insiste également oralement sur cette partie (la courbe intonative déclarative monte jusqu'à la pause, puis redescend).

2) La dislocation comme indiqué par le commentaire.

3) Il s'agit certes d'une construction de phrase méconnue en français mais devrait se retrouver dans d'autres langues (anglais et cantonnais).

Pour une information complète : [Constructions méconnues du français](https://books.openedition.org/pum/10266?lang=fr)

Answer (score 7):

J'ai eu le bénéfice de lire les autres réponses. Moins en ce qui concerne l'abstraction linguistique que la description du phénomène en français, surtout à l'écrit<sup>1</sup> :

> La **redondance** est le fait que la même fonction est exercée par
>   deux termes non coordonnés et apportant la même information dans la
>   même phrase. Tantôt ces termes sont identiques, tantôt l'un d'eux est
>   un pronom (surtout personnel et démonstratif), ou un synonyme, ou
>   encore un terme de sens vague comme *chose, procédé, fait*, etc.
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Boeck/Duculot,
>   14<sup>e</sup>, § 370 ]<sup>2</sup>

Le LBU14 en distingue plusieurs types : les redondances *grammaticales/habituelles*, celles *dues au souci de clarté*, d'autres qui sont *diverses et ordinairement peu justifiées*, et certaines qui sont ***expressives*** (LBU14 § 370). Un des procédés de la *redondance expressive* consiste en la définition présentée dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/36777)<sup>3</sup>, dont l'objectif est de *mettre en évidence*. Le terme mis en évidence peut être un sujet mais aussi un attribut ou un complément du verbe et les plus grands auteurs y ont eu recours (LBU14 § 373 b ; 237 b) :

> *Tel jeune prêtre, à peine ordonné depuis un an, ayant offert un lapin
>   privé à la servante d'un vieux curé, IL avait obtenu d'être demandé
>   pour vicaire* (Stendhal)
>  *Leur joie, toute en bourrades et en
>   éclat, ELLE n'a pas changé depuis Breughel* (Malraux)
>  *Cette sainte
>   montagne, au milieu de nos pays de l'Est, ELLE brille comme un buisson
>   ardent* (Barrès)
>  *Hugo, toujours gigantesque, s'il vient à succéder
>   à Lemercier dans l'Académie, IL a l'air de succéder à Napoléon, tant
>   il en parle tout d'abord* (Sainte-Beuve)
>  *Moi, je vous baptise avec
>   l'eau ; mais IL vient, celui qui est plus puissant que moi* (Bible,
>   trad. Crampon)

Soit dit en passant, la redondance pour des raisons de clarté (qui ne correspond pas à l'exemple de la question) était employée couramment même bien avant ces auteurs, jusqu'au 17<sup>e</sup> et au 18<sup>e</sup> dans l'ancienne langue : « Ceux qui les [= les pauvres] regardent des yeux corporels, ils n'y voient rien que de bas », Bossuet (LBU14 § 237 b note H1).

Enfin je n'ai pas l'expertise pour traiter des langues en général. D'autre part je ne vois pas ce qui empêcherait l'expressivité par la redondance ou la reprise d'éléments, que ce soit par le truchement du procédé qu'on a évoqué (qui implique cependant l'existence du pronom) ou d'une autre manière propre à la langue à laquelle on s'intéresserait.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Sur l'idée plus générale que la *thématisation* entraîne une redondance dans certains cas nécessitant l'emploi d'un pronom et sur le choix du pronom personnel *moi* (« Moi, mon âme est fêlée » Baudelaire), qu'on trouve surtout souvent dans la langue parlée et d'où résultent des constructions disloquées (qui étaient aussi assez courantes à l'écrit dans la langue ancienne qui s'en rapprochait) voir LBU14 § 229 + Note H et une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/36777).</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> Grevisse et Goosse proposent en note B sur le sujet de la *redondance* : Dessaintes, *La notion de « relais syntaxique »*, avril 1965, ds. Études classiques, à la p. 140</sub>
<sub><sup>3</sup> La référence à Grevisse 1993 est fort probablement [LBU13](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bon_Usage). La phrase exacte apparaît à LBU14/16 § 373 b, intitulé *Redondances expressives*.</sub>

Comment: Your characterizing the particular construction at issue (proper noun/noun phrase+pronoun) as a redundancy (& not necessarily as an example of left dislocation?) is more in line with what I was taught by my elementary-school grammar (granted, English) teachers in the mid-60s. In fact, we were taught that this redundant, "double-subject" construction was TOTALLY incorrect (again in English), and I can still feel the sting of that ruler on the tips of my fingers for daring to justify its use by quoting Dylan's "The times, THEY are a changin'" to teacher dearest!

Answer (score -4):

La raison de cet usage n'est certainement pas d'origine linguistique; je suis très conscient de son existence et il me semble ne faire  aucun doute que c'est un usage d'origine psychologique qui dérive d'une impropriété ou une insuffisance ressenti par le locuteur. Je crois pouvoir être sûr de cela. Ce à propos de quoi je serais beaucoup moins assuré c'est  la nature exacte de cette impropriété ressentie. Il me semble qu'elle pourrait avoir sa source dans la formalité d'expression que l'on peut relever dans les formes « sujet nominal – verbe – complément », dans un certain manque d'habitude pour qui serait habitué à l'échange verbal en grande partie au moyen de pronoms. Il est évident, néanmoins, qu'à la base, une part de la  responsabilité  est à imputer à une familiarisation insuffisante avec le langage ou une familiarisation trop exclusive avec des standard de langue inférieurs.

Je ne dispose pas d'autre information sur ce phénomène.

COMPLÉMENT (28/06/2019)

**I**

Il faut spécifier que la seule description possible du phénomène dans LBU comme cela a été déterminé dans cette [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/36783/17649) se trouve à la  § 373, b et que ses termes sont les suivants :

- « Redondances expressives,
- b) Un terme est mis en évidence au début ou à la fin de la phrase,
  et un pronom personnel ou démonstratif occupe la place normale
  de ce terme ».

Cependant, invoquer l'addition d'expressivité  n'est apparemment pas aussi vrai dans tous les cas que la constatation d'une expressivité incertaine, et donc on doit reconnaitre une forme du langage qui demeure illégitime; cela corrobore le fait que c'est une tournure trouvée moins élégante par qui a posé la question, (je la trouve moi-même lourde). LBU nous dit par exemple que Queneau s'en amuse :

- C'était pas qu'ELLE LES gênait, la famille les fossoyeurs, mais c'était l'heure d'aller déjeuner et ILS finiraient de LE remplir seulement après la soupe, les fossoyeurs le trou. (Dimanche de la vie, VII) [Quadruple redondance.]

Dans cet exemple, les doubles redondances sont vraiment exceptionnelles et rendent la construction extravagante, comme si donnée au lecteur/auditeur sous forme de recette à exécuter lui même. Ce cas-ci tout au moins semble échapper à la catégorisation que détermine LBU.

On remarque que d'après les exemples fournis, ce tour est associé à la langue populaire ou religieuse (Céline, interview, formule très familière, La Bible)¹; il ne faut pas confondre, il me semble, avec les utilisations qui ménagent  une véritable expressivité, ces utilisations où une certaine force/intonation inhabituelle est utilisée, comme dans la phrase de Proust par exemple ;

LIBRE, je ne LE suis à peu près jamais. (attribut)

Dans tous les cas ou presque tous dont parle qui a posé la question (il/elle « entend souvent ») il n'existe pas de prononciation spéciale du mot en redondance.

On ne trouve pas dans le parler populaire autant  de cas d'attributs mais les cas de sujet et les cas de complément sont courants.

Prenons un premier cas, donné par LBU et avec lequel peu d'entre nous ne sont pas familiers ;

- ÇA ne va pas, LA TÊTE ? formule très familière équivalant à « Vous déraisonnez. »

La forme « Ça va pas ? » ou « Non mais, ça va pas ? » peut paraitre ambigüe et l'impression est que le locuteur a besoin de spécifier le contexte, d'assurer qu'il/elle est compris/comprise. On remarquera que bon nombre de locuteurs se contentent d'un « Non mais ça va pas ? » prononcé avec force et qui suffit à exprimer ce qu'ils ressentent.

Un second cas ;

- ÇA va, LA FAMILLE ?

Ce contexte demande des formules complètes telles que les suivantes : « Comment va ta/votre famille ? », « Ta/Votre famille va-t-elle bien ? ».

L'impression ici est que l'idée qui envahit le locuteur tout d'abord est la question du bien-être et qu'elle est immédiatement traduite par un « ça va » qui est aussitôt émis; on suspecte que le locuteur n'a pas pris le temps où n'a pas eu le temps de penser ou qu'il rechigne à recourir aux moyens plus compliqués et qu'il rectifie finalement par l'addition de « la famille ». Je ne vois en aucune façon comment de l'expressivité serait ajoutée ni à quelle forme on l'ajoute ; les formes plus complexes à construire (« Comment va ta/votre famille ? ») n'ont rien à voir avec cette forme-ci. Il existe aussi la forme « Comment ça va, la famille ? », mais je ne ne vois pas en quoi elle est plus expressive que « Comment va la famille ? ». Il faut tenir compte que le processus  qui vient d'être avancé n'est pur que dans certains cas, les cas initiaux de la naissance de la forme ; viennent se superposer à ce principe celui de la nécessité de se conformer et celui de l'habitude prise, si bien que finalement le locuteur n'est pas nécessairement soumis à cette succession de stages de décision.

Encore un exemple pourra peut être indiquer que ces redondances ne sont pas d'un type aussi facilement justifiable  par le but d'introduire une expressivité accrue.

Il s'agit d'une mère qui, venant de réprimander un enfant dissipé, l'a déjà menacé de le mettre au lit ; comme elle n'obtient pas d'amélioration dans le comportement de l'enfant elle itère sa menace une dernière fois ;

- Je vais t'Y mettre AU LIT si tu continue à en faire à ta tête.

L'impression est que la mère de l'enfant n'est pas sure d'être comprise en n'utilisant que le pronom « y » et/ou que la référence (lit) a été mentionnée il y a trop longtemps pour que « y » ait l'effet voulu, c'est à dire être décodé comme signifiant « au  lit » ; il semblerait que au lieu de faire comme d'autres locuteurs qui ne pensent peut être pas en leur termes propres d'adulte et répètent tout simplement "au lit" en utilisant possiblement une intonation particulière (en scandant les mots, par exemple : Je—vais—te—mettre—au—lit.) elle se lance dans son parler adulte et rectifie par une confirmation en l'addition de « au lit ». On remarquera que ces mêmes personnes n'ont plus recours à la redondance dès qu'elles n'ont plus affaire à un locuteur aux aptitudes douteuses en matière de compréhension. Encore une fois, une forme caractérisée par la redondance inclut celle-ci de façon parasitique ; dans ce cas précis elle est forcée par l'amalgamation de deux contextes d'expression. Il n'est pas question d'expressivité, qui est un critère absolu : il ne peut s'agir d'expressivité accrue que du point de vue de l'enfant; pour un adulte il n'y a pas de différence.

Une utilisation récente de cette tournure  la concrétise dans un titre de  [chanson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUnyBqKfAH4), « Tout le monde il est beau ».  Cela est assez bizarre si l'on sait que le nom de la chanteuse, Zazie, a été inspiré par le livre « Zazie dans le métro » de  Raymond Queneau (voir ci-dessus) ( [ref](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zazie)). Il n'est pas clair qu'il s'agisse dune redondance expressive dans ce présent cas non plus; je pense plutôt à de l'affectation.

¹ <sub>(extrait de LBU) • Sujets (§ 237, b) : Hugo, toujours gigantesque, s'il vient à succéder à
Lemercier dans l'Académie, IL a l'air de succéder à Napoléon, tant il en
parle tout d'abord (S.-BEUVE, Mes poisons, p. 48). — Par bonheur, une
tête de vipère, C'est triangulaire [...]. Par bonheur, une peau de vipère,
C'est rugueux (H. BAZIN, Vipère au poing, I). [C'est le pronom placé
devant le verbe qui détermine l'accord.] — IL avait beaucoup changé,
Camus (SARTRE, Situation X, p. 196). [Texte d'une interview.] —
ÇA ne va pas, la tête ? formule très familière équivalant à Vous
déraisonnez. — Moi, je vous baptise avec l'eau ; mais IL vient, celui qui
est plus puissant que moi (Bible, trad. CRAMPON, Luc, III, 16).</sub>

**II**

Dans les cas identifiés par qui a posé la question il n'existe apparemment pas de terme pour nommer ce phénomène, et il faudrait parler de redondance fautive, en n'oubliant pas qu'il existe des cas à différencier clairement et que l'on appelle des cas de redondance expressive. Ces cas pourraient cependant ne pas être reconnus comme acceptables par tout le monde.

L'article suivant est une confirmation que plusieurs cas de redondance sont reconnus comme étant très contestables : [effet de style ou faute de français ?](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/culture-generale/la-france-elle-est-effet-style-faute-francais/).

Comment: Pourquoi les négatives votes ?

Comment: @Dimitris La raison semble être que certains lecteurs n'admettent pas que cet usage soit mis en question; leur raisonnement, ou plutôt leur position, qui rejette tout raisonnement, est que puisque il y a des gens qui le disent alors c'est automatiquement justifié. Personnellement, comme d'ailleurs certains utilisateurs professionnels du français, dont le philosophe Finkielkraut (ils sont cités dans les références) pensent que cette redondance est fautive (enfantine dit l'un d'eux); je suis arrivé à une conclusion similaire moi-même et de façon entièrement indépendante.

Comment: Personnellement j'ai jamais donné une note négative à quelqu'un. Évidemment on a le droit de le faire. Mais ça serait utile pour vous, afin que vous puissiez améliorer votre réponse, et pour nous les lecteurs de voir des explications pour les notes négatives.

Comment: @Dimitris Je suis tout à fait d'accord avec ce principe de justification des votes négatifs et il faut dire que ce n'est pas tout le monde qui vote sans justification, mais ceux qui le font sont beaucoup plus nombreux.

Comment: Bien sûr il est des plusieurs qui justifient leur vote. Il existe aussi des cas où le downvoting est entendu sans besoin d'explication explicite ; par exemple une réponse laconique fautive. Mais ici vous avez écrit vingt paragraphes ;  c'est pas une réponse naïve. Je peux comprendre le downvoting mais je voudrais lire pourquoi ☺.

Comment: @Dimitris Peut être faudrait-il exiger de ceux qui votent qu'ils aient le courage de leur opinions et que chaque fois, comme dans les demandes de clôture d'une question, leur nom d'utilisateur soit enregistré. (on dit  « Pourquoi les votes négatifs ? », pas « Pourquoi les négatives votes ? »)

Comment: @suiiurisesse Merci pour votre retour. Je n'ai pas suivi les échanges de cette réponse. Du coup, les deux derniers mois je n'étais pas trop actif à FSE. J'ai découvert donc des questions et réponses intéressantes que je n'ai pas vues.

Comment: @suiiurisesse Merci pour la suggestion:-)!

Comment: @LPH Merci pour la correction. Le vote et pas la vote, bien sûr. Cependant, pourquoi pas un négatif vote ? (Je rigole ; je sais pourquoi:-)!).