# Use of “c’est” with an adjective and plural nouns

Tags: grammaire, usage, accord, démonstratifs

I’ve seen countless times phrases like “C’est nul les examens” or “C’est beau les hommes” and I’m wondering if there’s a reason for this combination of c’est + a plural noun and whether it’s a recent type of construction.

I can’t really find anything about it through Google but I’ve seen it a lot online so I want to learn more about it.

Comment: If you are wondering why it does not take the form of "*Ce **sont** + (a plural noun)*", you are misinterpreting the structure. It's actually: "*C’est nul, les examens*" with a comma in between.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens i’m actually wondering why it’s that and not just “les examens sont nuls” and why ce is used as a subject to describe les examens

Comment: This construction is quite common in conversation, especially in spontaneous speech where you start to say something and then soon realise that you need to modify its construction a bit. Off the top of my head, a similar example: "*Je peux dire que **j’en ai, de la chance**, d’être au service d’un homme de cette trempe.*"

Comment: Anyway, the way I see it, I don't associate the subsequent plural noun "*les examens*" with the "Ce" at the head. It's like having two separate short clauses. In a manner of speaking, you can see it as: "*C’est nul, **je veux dire**, les examens*". By the way, you can also say: "*Les examens, c'est nul*".

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Just make it an answer, You've got it.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, There's no plural alternative in the present question, as I think @jlliagre's answer explains

Answer (score 6):

Your examples show a way to put the emphasis on a quality or a state (attribute) by moving the subject at the end of a sentence. It is common in spoken French. A comma is generally used.

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ce)

> **II.−** **Ce**, particule déictique ou base d'incidence.
> **A.−** [**Ce**, particule déictique en dehors de la fonction de base d'incidence] **C'est**.
> **1.** **C'est**, loc. de la mise en relief.
> ...
> **d)** C'est. [Valeur anaphorique d'anticipation, pour annoncer un suj. rejeté en fin de phrase]
> ♦ *C'est...,* + suj. :
>   23. Je me demande souvent comment vivent ceux qui n'ont rien à se reprocher. **C**'est si mystérieux une âme pure ! Green, *Journal*, 1943, p. 4.

There is no singular/plural discrepancy. ***Ce*** is a "neutral" pronoun but technically masculine/singular, ***est*** is singular, and both ***nul*** and ***beau*** are also masculine singular.

You can't say:

> **Ce sont belles, les sculptures.*

It's either:

> *C'**est beau**, les sculptures.* "That's beautiful, (the) sculptures."

or

> *Elles **sont belles**, les sculptures.* "They are beautiful, the sculptures."

Another example:

> *C'**est beau**, tes filles.* "That's beautiful, (seing) your daughters (as a whole,  e.g in a picture, a show.)"

while

> *Elles **sont belles**, tes filles.* "Your daughters (individually) are beautiful."

In the second form, the pronoun (elles) and the verb (sont) need to match the actual subjects (les maisons, tes filles) but in the first form, the pronoun and verb can't match them because there is only a single idiom usable here, *c'est*.

A similar pattern exists with ***ça*** :

> *Ça piqu**e**, les guêpes.*

or

> *Elles piqu**ent**, les guêpes.*

Note that there are other cases where *ce* can be used with a plural complement and a singular *être* verb, or with both a plural *être* and complement:

> C'est les vacances !
>
> Ce sont eux ! / C'est eux !

See [« C'est » ou « ce sont » devant le pluriel](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9371/cest-ou-ce-sont-devant-le-pluriel)

Comment: En exemple typique on aurait aussi pu citer quelques bons souvenirs d'enfant avec un *C'est les vacances!*.

Comment: @aCOSwt Ce n'est pas tout à fait la même chose, ou alors *C'est chouette/cool, les vacances*.

Answer (score -4):

LBU (*Le Bon Usage*) treats this question partially au 373 c and speaks of "redondance expressive".

> Un terme est mis en évidence au début ou à la fin de la phrase,
>   et **un pronom personnel ou démonstratif** occupe la place normale de ce terme :
>   • Sujets (§ 237, b) : Hugo, toujours gigantesque, s'il vient à succéder à
>   Lemercier dans l'Académie, IL a l'air de succéder à Napoléon, tant il en
>   parle tout d'abord (S.-BEUVE, Mes poisons, p. 48). — Par bonheur, une
>   tête de vipère, C'est triangulaire [...]. Par bonheur, une peau de vipère,
>   c'est rugueux (H. BAZIN, Vipère au poing, I). [C'est le pronom placé
>   devant le verbe qui détermine l'accord.] — IL avait beaucoup changé,
>   Camus (SARTRE, Situation X, p. 196). [Texte d'une interview.] —
>   ÇA ne va pas, la tête ? formule très familière équivalant à Vous
>   déraisonnez. — Moi, je vous baptise avec l'eau ; mais IL vient, celui qui
>   est plus puissant que moi (Bible, trad. CRAMPON, Luc, III, 16). [ Q
>   • Attributs (§ 247, d) : Libre, je ne LE suis à peu près jamais (PROUST)
>
> (user **LPH**'s bold type)

The information provided by "*Le Bon Usage*" leaves out a lot and that results from my point of view, in misrepresentation. Here is what I can deduce. It is a good idea for those really curious about this question of "redondance expressive/dislocation" to take note of the following question, as it is closely related: [Sujet+pronom à la place du sujet seul](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/36760/17649).

In the printed material you can't find "C'est nul les…" but you do find  "C'est beau les …"  . The first form is not to be construed as being the same as the second. The first does not mean "Les examens sont nuls.", which means nothing. Instead it means "Le système des examens est un système qui ne vaut rien.". This is modern French parlance of very recent origin and the redundancy or dislocation as others call it, is not expressive; it is so little expressive that nobody is able to explain what is this expressivity. The second form is of the type claimed ; it does mean "Les hommes sont beaux.". The question is why is there not the same nuance in the plain form. The answer, I believe, is that a plain assertion does not correspond to reality : yes, there are men who are beautiful but there are also men who are not so beautiful;  that is common knowledge and so the assertion hits one in the face as a flat statement that would have us redefine reality, an assertion that presents a new axiom. Instead, that is not what the author has in mind : he is concerned with the transcendence of that possible beauty in a certain number of the elements of the species to make it rather a characteristic of the species as a whole, to say that beauty is inherent to that species : "On the whole, a man is a beautiful creature.", "There is beauty in the human species.". This English translation shows a certain symmetry: the expected subject is rejected at the end, an adverb (there) is used to introduce the central concept (beauty). That is what the expressiveness consists in and some will probably be able to add complements to that and/or make adjustments.

It must be reckoned that not all forms on the morphological model of "expressive redondance" really belong to the category; it is only justified through special contexts that good writers are more apt to discern. There are nowadays people aware of the fact that this redundancy can be nothing but childish speech ([effet de style ou faute de français](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/culture-generale/la-france-elle-est-effet-style-faute-francais/)).
The form "Les examens c'est nul." shows that there is nothing in it but approximate recoding of the normal meaning of words, that being so out of an unability to form coherent thoughts, whatever the reason. We all know that such a way of expressing the idea wouldn't do in a serious discussion. The "expressive redundancy" is inexistent; the utterance is merely a case of  childish speech as characterised by the philosophers and journalists mentioned in the article shown above, an inchoate attempt at normal expression.

Comment: Au cas où tu te demandes pourquoi tes réponses ont souvent des votes négatifs (je précise que je n'ai pas mis de vote sur ta réponse), je vois deux raisons : d'abord des phrases trop complexes et alambiquées pour ce que tu veux dire, aussi bien en français et en anglais. N'oublie pas que la plupart des gens ici apprennent le français, une réponse droit au but et concise, souvent c'est l'idéal. Parfois je vois des pavés sur des questions auxquelles on pourrait répondre en 2 lignes... Je ne mets jamais de vote sans avoir lu, mais ça me donne pas envie de lire.

Comment: Ensuite, les opinions assez tranchées sur ce qu'on doit dire ou ne pas dire. Je vois souvent dans tes réponses des recommandations pour des phrases qui ne sont pas idiomatiques, ou bien des avis négatifs sur des expression qui font partie du langage courant. Les réponses devraient refléter le français parlé par les gens, pas le seulement le "bon usage" ou les recommandations de l'académie française que parfois personne ne suit.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Merci pour ces opinions, qui me semblent sincères ; je reconnais que je suis difficile à lire, je peux moi-même ne pas savoir ce que j'ai voulu expliquer parfois lorsque je me relis. Je dois dire quand même qu'il y a des questions difficiles et donc que l'on ne peut pas traiter sans aborder des idées complexes ; on ne peut pas toujours exprimer ces choses-là avec des phrases et des termes simples. Celle-ci en est une et ce que j'essaie d'exprimer dans ma réponse, peut-être pas trop bien, reste néanmoins mes convictions.

Comment: Probablement qu'il y a une voie du milieu mais non, je ne suis pas de mauvaise foi. J'ai à bien des reprises tenté de faire des suggestions similaires. Il n'y a pas d'argument difficile, simplement montrer qu'une redondance ne correspond pas aux catégories visées au LBU et qu'elle est très répétitive et voilà, on peut dire qu'elle est « moins justifiable ». Dans tous les cas il s'agit simplement d'un relâchement et non pas d'une tentative incohérente de s'exprimer. Même le français relâché est du français. Fais comme tu l'entends. Tu as droit à tes opinions mais stp sois juste dans tes propos.

Comment: @personne D'accord, mais de ce « moins justifiable » qui glisse facilement vers un « pas justifiable du tout » on doit  aussi s'assurer ; je ne prétend pas avoir fait cela non plus, j'ai seulement une forte impression que c'est la vérité et elle a été confirmée par des personnes dont la vie est immergée dans l'utilisation de la langue ; tâche très difficile on n'en sort pas avec 2 ou 3 lignes. Vous parlez d'une étude qui entraine si elle doit être sérieuse, l'examen de centaines d'échantillons de langage parlé et écrit **et** avant tout l'établissement d'une base de critère de jugement précis.